# NG serve takes long time to start

Tags: angular

I'm working on Angular 9.1.4 node 14.0.

Now I'm facing a trouble which is whenever trying to run

```
ng serve
```

its taking long time to start. I'm trying to compile a theme I have got from themeforest. no installation issue at all with **npm install** which all works fine and I also updated all the packages in packages.json as well.

Still the serve command is very slow

Comment: What do you mean by long time? Could you please share what it means exactly? (How many seconds, minutes, hours etc.)

Comment: OK.. It took around 40 mins first...

Answer (score 6):

Most of the time ng serve takes too long because of `@angular-devkit` downgrading the version might work. Since you are using angular 9 you can enable ivy compilation in tsconfig file by adding 
`"angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": true }`

Comment: I have the same problem my ng serve takes more than 10 mins to run. Now I got 2 min.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the `--source-map=false` attribute for Angular to load only the stuff that it needs, and will recompile only those parts of your application, that have been modified.

```
ng serve --source-map=false
```

In my case (Angular v.11), `ng serve` takes about 1 minute to serve the app, but the `ng-serve --source-map=false` takes somewhere from 10 to 30 seconds. Moreover, changes are applied much more faster.

Comment: --source-map option is obsolete

Answer (score 2):

Use the --verbose option to see what's going wrong behind the scenes:

```
ng serve --verbose
```

Answer (score -3):

If you have the `package-lock.json` in your file try to **delete it**. It may help the speed for at least 2%?

I have the same problem my `ng serve` takes 4 mins to run or to show that `√ Compiled successfully.`

Now it takes 2-3 mins.